# Calling PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey() gives "error:0906D06C:lib(9):func(109):reason(108)"

Tags: c, openssl

Reading in a key file, I pass the data to `PEM_read_bui_RSAPrivateKey`, and am rewarded with:

> error:0906D06C:lib(9):func(109):reason(108)

I was able to look up lib 9 (PEM, makes sense), but wasn't able to find anything about the `func` or `reason`.  I'm guessing `func(109)` is `PEM_read_bui_RSAPrivateKey()`, but it could just as easily be some internal thing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the public key file instead of the private key file.

Based on my searches, this is one of several different things that can cause this particular error, but I didn't see any of them mention this particular cause.